# Wordpress wp_get_attachment_image() to display static image

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I am building my header file and I cant figure out how to use the wp_get_attachment_image() to display my logo.  The path to the logo is images/logo.png.

Most examples I found online use this to display images dynamically

Comment: What is the absolute path to the image?

Comment: themes/newtheme/images/logo.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can echo the image via:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png'; ?>">
```

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` returns the "uri" for your active theme.

Read more about [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) in [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri).

You can't use `get_attachment_image()` in this case, because the image hasn't been attached to WordPress via the Media Uploader.